# Cannot resolve method TimeUnit line

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Below is my code for an Activity.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tx3.setText("song.mp3");

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setClickable(false);
        b2.setEnabled(false);

        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mediaPlayer.start();

                finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                if (oneTimeOnly == 0){
                    seekBar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                    oneTimeOnly = 1;
                }
                   /* Problem below line */
                tx2.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECOND.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTE.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes())));
            }
        });
    }
```

It is showing the error cannot resolve method at line where I used `toMinutes`. and text is red color. 
I have apply `Alt+Enter` but does not work. 
any idea how to solved it?

Comment: What is the parent class...?

Comment: Cann't understand

Comment: Which method are you is your IDE reffering to?

Comment: It looks like an import problem. Is `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` present in your imports?

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported this class:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```

Replace it with this one:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Comment: Aren't these the same?  Can you please explain how/what this solves?

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same issue in eclipse, where my import for TimeUnit was erroring out (i.e.: import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit can not be resoved).
I was able to fix it after re configuring my Build Path to Workspace default JRE [which was latest in my case].
After Config Build Path- I got my import error resolved. Attaching snap [image: BuildPathConfigration]-

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fastest way is using this function:

```
String msToString(int ms) {

    int hh = ms / 3600000;
    ms -= hh * 3600000;
    int mm = ms / 60000;
    ms -= mm * 60000;
    int ss = ms / 1000;

    return String.format("%d min, %d sec", mm, ss);
}
```

Your code will be simplyfied to

```
tx2.setText(msToString(finalTime));
```